# Get Telegram group members (group has no invite link and no name)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

How to get list of all members from private Telegram group which I participate,
by having just a group id (like `s1234567890_12345678901234567890`) and using Python Telethon library?

Later, I want to send private message from my account to the few of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`client.iter_dialogs()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs), which will return list of all your personal dialogs.

In loop, you can compare dialog with the correct ID and break from the loop. After that - use it with [`client.iter_participants()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants).

Comment: Thanks. Also, I found a good wrapper for this function `client.get_dialogs()`. Looks like it should work better.

Comment: @wowkin2 its better to use iter_dialogs, as get_dialogs can be very slow

Comment: The reason to favour `iter_dialogs` over `get_dialogs` is that `iter_dialogs` is lazy, while `get_dialogs` has to fetch them all up-front.